# Apache Redirect TO IP Address (non-URL)

Tags: apache-2.2, ip, redirect, https

I've been trying to redirect web traffic from **HTTP** to **HTTPS** by adding the line to the `httpd.conf` file:

```
Redirect permanent / https://100.100.100.100
```

but to no avail. The browser response is [`Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/The_page_is_not_redirecting_properly).

I understand that it works for domain names but my server doesn't use one. Is there any way around this/what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Have you configured Apache to listen on port 443 and referenced an SSL certificate? Please post the host configuration from httpd.conf

Comment: One of the problems with using a permanent redirect is that Firefox **will** cache it.  (Maybe not the redirect delivered over SSL but definitely the one delivered over non-SSL.) Even once you fix this problem, Firefox will continue to give you that error message until you clear that part of its cache.  Use `curl -I http://100.100.100.100` to check what response code you get back without having to worry about caching.

Comment: @JudasIscariot1651 Yes SSL certificate is installed and when I enter 'https://' 100.100.100.100' in browser it works no problem. I want 'http://' 100.100.100.100 to redirect to https://...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that your Redirect line is in a part of the config file that affects both the SSL and non-SSL parts.  Therefore, even when you request the SSL version you still get a redirect to the SSL version.

If you have a part of the config file that is for non-SSL only, move the Redirect there.  If not, convert it to a RewriteRule and use a RewriteCond in front of it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule / https://100.100.100.100/ [R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

Apache has a special page titled "[When not to use mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/avoid.html)"

Follow their examples

> To redirect http URLs to https, do the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost >

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    # ... SSL configuration goes here
</VirtualHost >
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mod_rewrite:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]
```